# Length of multidimensional array with smarty

Tags: count, smarty, variable-length

I want to know the length of a multidimensional array in smarty.

I have:`{foreach itme=$i from=$var}{/foreach}`
I try with `{$var.$id|@count}`
but not work.
How can I have the length for use this in a `{for}` cicle?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is good. You are right about using @count within a foreach loop. but your code contains some errors.

```smarty
{foreach itme=$i from=$var}{/foreach}
       // ^----- should be item, $i should be just i without $ symbol in front 

{$var.$id|@count}
     // ^-------- this should be just $i according to your foreach loop and without $var.
```

So a functional code would be :

```smarty
{foreach item=id from=$var}
    {$id|count}
{/foreach}
```

Note that in Smarty 3 you haven't to add @ symbol in front of the count modifier. It is just ignored.